# How do I add an AppImage application to favorites in GNOME shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, appimage, favorites

I have an application (an AppImage) that I start with `./KDevelop.AppImage &`

When it starts there is an icon in my favorites bar (Ubuntu Dock), but when I right click on that there is no option to "add to favorites".

How can I add this to favorites?

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Ubuntu 18.04: When you run the appimage it asks you if it should integrate it into the system. If you choose yes then you can search it on the shell and right-clicking on it (before running) will give you the option to add to Favorites.

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: How do we do this if we accidentally do not integrate into the system the first time?

Comment: A comment on this answer made by a new user as a separate (now-deleted) answer said: "*You should mention that integration to system works only after installing [AppImage Launcher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases)*"

Comment: Another problem with this approach is that when you click on the icon in the launcher, it creates another icon in the launcher for the app, so that you technically have it twice in the launcher.  And every time you click on the favorite icon, it creates another session and another icon.

Comment: This is not true in 23.04. No question is asked

Answer (score 2):

In the first run of APPImage,you may miss the "integrate and run" button and choose the "run" button like

[image]

If you don't mind install again, I'm sure you know what to do.
But if you can't, AppImageLauncher may help.
https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `StartupWMClass` to the `.desktop` file of the launcher of the AppImage. otherwise your running instance will not get associated with the .desktop launcher and **Add to Favourites** option will not be there.

for example `~/.local/share/application/inkscape.desktop` file should look like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Inkscape
Exec=/opt/inkscape/Inkscape.AppImage
Icon=/opt/inkscape/inkscape-logo.svg
Comment=Draw Freely
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Utility;
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=org.inkscape.Inkscape
```

To find the StartupWMClass entry of your application use

1. for wayland use [looking-glass](https://askubuntu.com/a/1362816/1645245)
2. for xorg run `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` in terminal and click on your application's window