# How can I get the Wayland Application ID (WM_CLASS equivalent) for a running application?

Tags: gnome-shell, wayland

To get Gnome-Shell to correctly detect that an application is already running I need to specify the StartupWWClass in the desktop file. On X11 this is easy to get using xprop (to get WM_CLASS), but on Wayland I cannot find a way to get this information (called in Wayland the application ID I believe). Is there a way to get it?

PS: I'm aware that in general Wayland doesn't allow getting information about other apps like X11 did. However, this information is not particularly sensitive, so I figure either Wayland or Gnome-Shell (the compositor) may have made an exception for this identifier to allow people to determine what applications call themselves and which applications are running.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Any workarounds so far?

Answer (score 6):

On Gnome-Shell you can use a built-in tool [looking glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass).

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `lg` and press enter. In the top-right panel select "Windows".

[image]

You can start inspecting by clicking on any title in the revealed list. Just make sure you don't click on an app.

[image]

You will find `wm_class` right away in the list of windows or as the last item in the list of attributes.

[image]

Comment: What would be the command to get this information?

Comment: There's a convenient gnome shell extension:  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2296/looking-glass-button/